# How to add a custom URL on the "Proceed to checkout", button for a specific product category [WooCommerce]

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements, checkout

I'm trying to add a custom URL on the "Proceed to checkout" button for a specific product category.

I've successfully added a custom URL on it by using the following code, however now I want to show a different URL based on the products, in the cart.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_checkout_url', 'dj_redirect_checkout');

function dj_redirect_checkout($url) {
     global $woocommerce;
     if(is_cart()){
          $checkout_url = 'https://example.com';
     }
     else { 
     //other url or leave it blank.
     }
     return  $checkout_url; 
}
```

For example, I've two categories (Tradeline 1 & Tradeline 2) on my WooCommerce website. I would like to place a different URL on the "Proceed to checkout" button for the other category if it is in the cart.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You So Much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should loop through cart items and check if any item has one of the terms you wanna target. You should use slugs of "Tradeline 1", "Tradeline 2", probably it is "tradeline-1".

Here is a quick POC:

```
$cat_in_cart = false;

foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

    $product = $cart_item['data'];

    if ( has_term( 'tradeline-1', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        $cat_in_cart = true;
        break;
    }
}

if( $cat_in_cart == true ) // do stuff
```

Useful reference: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-check-product-category-cart/

Cheers!

Comment: Hi 

Thank you for the code. 

Where should I place the links? OR Do I need to place your code, with-in my code? Sorry, I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: No prob! Yes, the code is a proof of concept to integrate your code. Not super easy if you are not familiar with PHP.

Comment: Thank You So Much. 

I've managed to integrate it with my code.